# Required field validation in radio button using PHP

Tags: php, validation, radio-button

I am trying to add required field validation to a page where there are 5 radio buttons with the same name. If the user clicks the button to proceed to the next page an error should be displayed, below is the code I am currently using but it is not doing anything

```
<?php
if (empty($_POST) === false) {
$required_fields = array('q1');
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
if (empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true) {
    $errors[] = 'Please select a number between 1-5';
    break 1;
    }
}
if (empty($errors) === true) {
    if(!isset($_POST['q1'])){ 
    $errors[] = "Please select a number between 1-5"; 
} 

}
}
?>      

<h1>Assessment</h1>

<?php
if (isset($_GET['success']) && empty($_GET['success'])) {

} else {
if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
$updateassessment = array(
    'q1'                => $_POST['q1'],
);

updateassessment($updateassessment);
header ('Location: question2.php');
exit();

} else if(empty($errors) === false){
echo output_errors($errors);
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">

<p class="p1">
Question 1</p>
<p class="p4">
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM traits WHERE Question = 'q1'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['fromtrait'] . ' - ' . $row['totrait'];
  echo "<br />";
  }


?></p>

<p class="p3">
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="1" />
1
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="2" />
2
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="3" />
3
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="4" />
4
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="5" />
5


</p><br><br>
  <input type="image" src="Images/image1.png" name="submit" align="right"/>
</form>
```

I got this to work by adding

```
if (empty($errors) === true) {
    if(!isset($_POST['q1'])){ 
    $errors[] = "Please select a number between 1-5"; 
} 

}
```

Comment: how does the form look like?

Comment: Edited the code above to include the form

Answer (score 0):

You have to set action="" to action="`<filename>`" (in your form) else PHP won't know where to "go" after user submits the form. Filename refers to the php-file.

Comment: Tried that and it hasnt worked, the exact code works on other pages for textboxes but not radio buttons in this case :/

Comment: No that doesnt work either :/ I know its probably something silly but im not seeing it

Comment: Still continues on to the next page when i add the code you posted there now

Answer (score -1):

by it's nature PHP is a inefficient way to validate forms because the page has to reload for any PHP checks to be done. perhaps a client side solution can be implemented, but if not try this to see if it does what you're looking for...

```
$required_fields = array('q1');
foreach ($required_fields as $field) {
    if (isset($_POST[$field]) && !empty($_POST[$field])) {
         echo $field." was set<br>\n";
    } else {
        echo "validation for $field failed!<br>\n";
    }
}
```

Also ... is Javascript an option? jquery ValidationEngine is quite useful and has checks for many of your field requirements, and validate before the form is submitted to mitigate needs tor PHP to do the checks.

Comment: -1 NEVER use ONLY client-side validation. You can use client-side validation to make it more user-friendly, but never rely on it! Users CAN bypass client-side validation easily.

Comment: Tried adding this just to test it and got the following error:

[23-Apr-2013 00:27:56 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in C:\xampp\htdocs\lr\question1.php on line 11

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld... I did not say ONLY use client side validation, i advised that if he is looking for validation prior to the page re-loading he might consider it because PHP can not validate BEFORE you submit the form. Thanks for the down vote though.

Comment: @kerriPower , i had a couple typo, change the foreach to update the 's' at the end of $required_feld and thange the $post to $_POST. sorry

Comment: that's because im still making mistakes .. change the !empty([$field]) to !empty($_POST[$field]). hasty answers .. my bad.

Comment: Ok - When the page loads im getting the message validation for q1 failed! at the top of the page but it still allows me to click the button to proceed to the next page without a radio button being clicked?

Comment: That is because the PHP validation does not occur until after you submit for form and the page reloads to itself.  if you want something to validate the form before the form submits (and hence reloads the page) you will need a client side validation like i mentioned above. PHP only executes (or validates in this case) when the page first loads, not when you click submit on the form. PHP  can not do anything once the page is done building and you can see it.

Comment: It works on other pages though - If i dont fill in a field in my registration page the errors are displayed on the same page when i click on the button?

Comment: i'd have to see the code on that page to know how it's validating. can you provide the url? perhaps i can look at the produced html to see if/how it's working there and explain.

Comment: No, as it is only for a project the website is not live. I could forward you a copy of the registration page and the page with the radio buttons if you want to email me at kerrip90@hotmail.co.uk

Comment: anything you could send would be fine. i'll see what i can figure out. if you could sent the php file i'll do what i can to check it out.

Comment: That would be great thanks - If you email me i will reply with the files

Comment: i don't see any email address in your user profile .. perhaps you can email me using the address in my profile.

Comment: @Silvertiger - Ok, you didn't say that use clientside validation only, but you said "PHP is a inefficient way to validate forms" and  "Perhaps a client side solution can be implemented. It's easy to interpret that as "It's ok to use javascript instead of PHP-validation" (That was I thought when I read it)